# AttributeError: Unknown property column

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, error-handling, histogram

the histogram code was working fine, but I got an error message, after creating a function for my plot. [note: I have to put it in a function, because I want to show the visualization in the slideshow of Jupyter Notebook, but without the Code. So that would be a good way, that only the function call is shown then.]

```
def plotX(df):
df.hist(column='x', figsize=(10,5), bins=105,color="teal")
plt.title("show x")
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
```

Then I call the function:

```
plotX(df.x)
```

I got an Error Message then:

```
 AttributeError: Unknown property column
```

The Histogram is shown after the Error Message. But the Error is in my Slideshow too. Any ideas for this Error Message?

Comment: what type is `df` and `df.x`.

Comment: try `plotX(df)` instead of `plotX(df.x)`

Comment: when I try plotX(x), i get a NameError: name 'x' is not defined

Comment: df' is a pandas dataframe with several columns and df.x is int64

Comment: I think if you supply `df.x`  you should remove `column='x',`. If you supply `df` `column="x"` makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be solved in two ways.

```
def plotX(df):
    df.hist(column='x',figsize=(10,5), bins=105,color="teal")
    plt.title("show x")
    plt.xlabel('x')
    plt.ylabel('y')

plotX(df)
```

**OR**

```
def plotX(df):
    df.hist(figsize=(10,5), bins=105,color="teal")
    plt.title("show x")
    plt.xlabel('x')
    plt.ylabel('y')

plotX(df.x)
```

You got error because hist takes a array of elements. When you say, `df.x` it gives a pandas series which is enough for creating a histogram and don't need to mention `column=x`.